How can I import data from several sources to a single output file with Pentaho?
I have a transformation process that gets data from several data sources and joins them into a single CSV output.
This process is a raw job that removes the previous information and loads the data that is currently fetched from the data sources.
What I need is for the output CSV to keep the data that is no longer returned by the data sources, update the ones that change, and add the new ones.
In other words, I need to keep old information, update the changes and add the new records.
I am fairly new to Pentaho and so far have not been able to do this.
Can you help me with the flow I need to implement?

You can use the merge rows (diff) step to compare 2 differents versions of your dataset. Keys is used to merge rows and Values to compare them.
Then use a Switch Case to process rows as you wish based on these flags  :
identical :
The key was found in both rows, and the compared values are identical.
changed :
The key was found in both rows, but one or more compared values are different.
new :
The key was not found in the reference rows.
deleted :
The key was not found in the compare rows.

If doing this, do keep in mind the rows need to be ordered by the comparisson key, which might be troublessome for big files, since they need to be read fully in flow, before they can be ordered. So you probably also need to increase the batch sizes if using this for files > 20k lines.  Therefore loading csv one by one to db and fetching distinct in order, which is the same order as writing to csv last time, could be advantagous for very big files. At least a lot faster.
